# Crash during video playback

Tags: crash, mythtv

After many years of no-issues running Ubuntu-Mate 16LTS for MythTV, a drive failure meant I finally upgraded to Ubuntu-Mate 20.04LTS. However, I'm suffering from repetitive crashes either during playback or often while paused. I'm using MythTV but it also seems to effect VLC but not streaming from things like Amazon-Prime or other web services.  If I don't play any recordings, the MythTV Backend happily goes about it's business, even when using DLNA/uPNP from another device.  But when I play locally, after a seemingly random period; maybe a few short recordings, or after a few minutes (but often while paused) - the box will become unresponsive, clock stops and although the keyboard lights work, none of the shutdown shortcuts do - a forced shutdown (long press) is the only apparent fix.

I've reinstalled a few times; including testing with Xubuntu, straight-Ubuntu, and back to Mate - each suffering the same crash, completely unresponsive hard-power off being the only option. I did try switching to LinHES but wile that didn't seem to have this issue - I simply didn't get on with Arch (at least the little I played).

```
Currently: Linux mythtv 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's a Gigabyte BRIX BPCE 3130 - with 8gb and a Single non-SSD Drive. OS installed on a single EXT4 partition, while MythTV is recording/playing from XFS.

```
Onboard Graphics (hwinfo):  Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
```

It's a pretty much a vanilla  installation, obvious with MythTV (installed via PPA - as per MythTV WIKI), MythWeb, VLC but very little else.

I've tried to reviewed the logs and can't see anything obvious myself (not that I know anything about firefighting a failure like this), I took the action of directing the output of "tail -f" from all logs, and scanned that for anything - below is the final minute from that file (there is a clear 5minute gap between these and the previous log). MythFrontend was playing at the time.

```
==> /var/log/auth.log <==
Apr 28 21:39:01 mythtv CRON[24991]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
==> /var/log/syslog <==
Apr 28 21:39:01 mythtv CRON[24992]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
==> /var/log/auth.log <==
Apr 28 21:39:01 mythtv CRON[24991]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
==> /var/log/syslog <==
Apr 28 21:39:14 mythtv systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Apr 28 21:39:14 mythtv systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Apr 28 21:39:14 mythtv systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
```

I see a few of these

```
Apr 28 21:30:18 mythtv mythfrontend.real: mythfrontend[22846]: N CoreContext mythplayer.cpp:2027 (PrebufferEnoughFrames) Player(2): Waited 1069ms for video buffers AUULuAAAAUAAALAA
Apr 28 21:30:18 mythtv mythfrontend.real: mythfrontend[22846]: N CoreContext mythplayer.cpp:2017 (PrebufferEnoughFrames) Player(2): To see more buffering messages use -v playback
Apr 28 21:32:29 mythtv mythfrontend.real: mythfrontend[22846]: I CoreContext screensaver-x11.cpp:156 (RestoreDPMS) ScreenSaverX11Private: DPMS Reactivated 1
```

and a few of these too (which I guess is my configuration, but auto is OK, and until I have a stable system I'm avoiding spending time fine tuning things.

```
==> /var/log/mythtv/mythfrontend.log <==
Apr 28 20:30:45 mythtv mythfrontend.real: mythfrontend[22846]: E Decoder decoders/avformatdecoder.cpp:4781 (ProcessAudioPacket) AFD: Unknown audio decoding error
```

finally - I see lots of these

```
==> /var/log/syslog <==
Apr 28 20:26:50 mythtv kernel: [ 9456.170539] perf: interrupt took too long (8112 > 8101), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 24500
```

I'd like some help resolving this issue - so any feedback would be appreciated.  I guess I've not included enough info with this initial post, but I'm happy to provide what is required.  I enjoyed years of hassle free TV using 16LTS, so I have high hopes for similar longevity with 20.04.

Kind regards and thanks in advance,
Brian

Comment: You mention needing to power off as the only solution; so by this do you mean a SysRq command direct to the kernel didn't provide a clean shutdown or other? (ie. it's not just a stuck GUI but a kernel panic & the complete system is down? or are you just not mentioning power-off button as you've not explored safer alternatives?)   You mention trying different alternatives & using 5.8 or HWE kernel?  Did you try the GA kernel option of 20.04?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - it seems to be as you describe, a kernel panic; but I’ll reconfirm that again because I use a wireless keyboard; so have just plugged in a cabled one for that retest.  i shall also readup and investigate the GA option over the weekend.

Comment: current version_signature is: Ubuntu 5.8.0-50.56~20.04.1-generic 5.8.18

Comment: Ok - its just gone down after a recording being paused for ~10mins.
alt+ctrl+del has no action

Comment: Sorry - here is the full update (albeit I’m waiting for a second crash)
Ok - its just gone down after a recording being paused for ~10mins.
alt+ctrl+del has no action
alt+sysrq+p has no action
Seems that the keyboard lights stopped responding this time too.
i’ve just reset to have another go because I had both keyboards plugged in - so, just the TV Tuner and wired keyboard this time.
Paused TV at 1107hrs, still ok at 1136hrs, so I’ll post this update and report back later.
Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Why would Ctrl+Alt+del (it's not DOS/windows 98) do anything? or alt+sysrq+P?  I would have tried a REISUB command to tell your machine to safely reboot  (as that alone tells you heaps, but adjust for whatever you feel is appropriate).  if you don't know the commands, a quick search online with a phone is often best, and the wikipedia page on sysrq usually appears at the top of a search and is as good as any for sysrq commands. Given your "p" is "*Output the current registers and flags to the console*" what were you trying to accomplish with it?  (did you have a console connected? & active?)

Comment: Old habits die hard I’m afraid.... it’s just failed again, at 1221hrs and the keyboard lights are unresponsive as too alt+sysrq+B and the other suggested combos (which i did have to look up last time, i tried several but only posted (& in hindsight incorrectly) ‘p’ which i apologies for).
i’m wondering if the timing is anything because i turned off the monitor (a Samsung TV via HDMI) after the last post (already disabled screensaver) - but the time of the clock was within a minute of when i turned the screen on again... may be nothing.......
i’ll have a look at the suggested GA Kernel next.

Comment: Ok - i have downgraded my kernel to GA based on this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack. 

But: have also found that my RAM, while it returns OK from memtest, it stops at 47% during the on-boot test.
Just reseated the RAM (wishful I know!)  and rhe same issue.     Just sent an email to the manufacturer with hope of saving £40!

Is there a hardware check tool you can recommend?

I assume you’ll consider this a hardware problem and best to fix that before trying to look at anything else.

Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: It depends what you're talking about with regards testing hardware... to test PSU (even good components will fail with poor power) it's a multi-meter, to check the motherboard it's your eyes (swollen caps etc though I've used a clean pinky finger too)... Good memtest software is provided with Ubuntu ISOs (the option appears on boot except if it's detected to not be allowed for legal reasons with certain hardware configs; ie. same thumb-drive may have it show on one box, but not another)

Comment: I’ll sort the RAM and start again.  Thanks for your time guiverc, keep well!
Brian.